# Docusign - Name Field Data Population

Tags: docusignapi

Currently using the Docusign API to create an envelope request.

Is there a way to set the Name field as NULL or BLANK and configure my docusign template to prompt the user to enter that field when its blank but to allow them to edit that data if its pre-populated ?

In some cases we know this value and in other cases its not known and the user would have to type that data in at the time they sign (e.g. if they are Company Signatory).

Is there a way to configure Docusign to support this type of logic ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `name` or `email` tab in DocuSign, the system automatically populates those tabs with the recipient's name and email.  If you want an editable name field do not use the name tab, use a `text` tab instead.

Comment: Thanks for the shout out. Isn't the name field mandatory ?  How would I map a text field to the name field I want the person to enter their name into ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Name fields are one type of DocuSign tab, text fields are another type.  They are not linked to each other.  Would be easiest if you post your actual JSON in your question.